# Why my wordpress plugin is not working

Tags: wordpress

I want to creat a simple plugin that attaches my style to all pages.
This is my code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Super Plugin
*/

function mr_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'forms', plugins_url( 'forms.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'forms', plugins_url( '', __FILE__ ) );
    echo '/* style-echo */ <style>
        .social-icons{display:none!important;}

        </style>';
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mr_scripts', 99 );

?>
```

The plugin is activated. Unfortunately i dont see the changes on my website. Please help solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Plugin is written with a lot of mistakes in it. What you want is probably the following:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Super Plugin
*/

function mr_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'forms', plugins_url( 'forms.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'forms');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mr_scripts', 99 );


function my_head_style() {
    echo '/* style-echo */ <style>
        .social-icons{display:none!important;}

        </style>';
}

add_action('wp_head','my_head_style');

?>
```

More information on correct use of register / enqueue of styles:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpfull!